# how to initialize vector from array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

how would you transfer members of an array to a vector.

Comment: Please provide the full declaration for `points`.

Comment: `int values[] = {1, 2 ,3}; 
std::vector<int> copies(std::begin(values), std::end(values));`

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer"?

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize it with the vector constructor that takes two iterators, like this:

```
std::vector<chair> points(chairarray, chairarray + arraysize);
```

As a member of your house class, you would do that in the initialization list:

```
house::house(int arraysize, chair* chairarray)
    :points(chairarray, chairarray + arraysize)
{}
```

Comment: why do you add chairarray and arraysize?

Comment: @Jane: Because that gives you a pointer to the end of your array (or rather, one element after the end), and the vector is initialized with all the elements starting from `chairarray` up to but not including that point. It's analogous to what `std::vector::end` returns (or any container's end member function, for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use something like the following:

```
points.insert(points.end(), chairarray, chairarray + arraysize);
```

(This is making an assumption that the elements of `chairarray` and the elements of `points` is the same.)

You are likely segfaulting because you are trying to modify members of `points` that do not yet exist.  You can't, for example, set `points[0]` if the current size of `points` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the segment fault issue, just as @md5i had mentioned, the statement `std::vector<chair> points;` was to initialize `points` with default constructor, so the size is zero.

there are 4 methods for `vector`container to initialize object, here are some code snippet form STL source:

```
explicit vector(const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
: _Base(__a) {}

vector(size_type __n, const _Tp& __value,
     const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type()) 
: _Base(__n, __a)
{ _M_finish = uninitialized_fill_n(_M_start, __n, __value); }

explicit vector(size_type __n)
: _Base(__n, allocator_type())
{ _M_finish = uninitialized_fill_n(_M_start, __n, _Tp()); }

vector(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x) 
: _Base(__x.size(), __x.get_allocator())
{ _M_finish = uninitialized_copy(__x.begin(), __x.end(), _M_start); }
```

what @Benjamin Lindley used was the last one, and `points.insert(points.end(), chairarray, chairarray + arraysize);` was one method in `vector`, so many ways to tackle your main question about "initialize vector from array" :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate elements in points first. Just add one line:

```
house::house(int arraysize, chair* chairarray)
{
    points.resize(arraysize); // add this
    for(int i=0; i<arraysize; ++i)
    {
        points[i].x=chairarray[i].x;
        points[i].y=chairarray[i].y;
     }
}
```

Generic copy can also save you lots of typing:

```
points.resize(arraysize);
std::copy(chairarray, chairarray+arraysize, points.begin());
```